# Subspace of bounded real sequences with trivial orthogonal space

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ be the space of all real sequences. Let $V$ be the subspace of all bounded real sequences equipped with

$$\langle f,g\rangle=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{f(n)g(n)}{n^2}$$

Find a subspace $U$ of $V$ with $U \neq 0$, $U \neq V$ and $U^
⊥ = 0$.

So that would mean that the only $g(n)$ which satisfies

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{f(n)g(n)}{n^2}=0 $$

for all $f \in U$ would be $g=0$.

So far I have tried testing all sequences that do not converge to $0$ and examining $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{f(n)}{n^2}$$

Am I on the right track?

I have also found out that there can be no $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(n)=0$, because you could define $g(n)=1$ for that $n$ and $0$ otherwise.

However my attempts have failed, as it seems to me that for every bounded sequence you can scale the summands by $g(n)$ so that the sum diminishes.

Any hints are welcome.

Comment: What happens if you take the subspace of all bounded and finite sequences? (Here finite means, that only $a_n \neq 0$ for finite many entries.) Of course, there are also other possible choices for $U$. (You need that $U$ is not closed, but dense with respect to the above-defined inner-product.) Note that the set of all sequences, which don't converge to $0$, is not a subspace!

Comment: I have misunderstood the problem. I think it works. Thank you.